# But interesting all the same - how to understand this?

Tags: phrase-meaning

How one would understand a phrase:

> **But interesting all the same**

What is it's usage? Really puzzling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All the same** is a common phrase meaning "despite what was just said." You use it when you are making a statement that seems to disagree with what you said previously. For example:

> The movie was extremely long. But (it was) interesting **all the same | just the same**.
>
> My daughter is very difficult sometimes, but I love her **just the same**.

This page has some a more complete definition and other examples: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/all-the-same-just-the-same